# HowTo: Tikz 3d Plot of an object

Tags: tikz-pgf

Hi I have problem with plotting an integration area. In the `x-y`-plane the area is bounded by the polynoms 3x^2-1 and 3-x^2. In `z`-direction there are the limits `z=0` and `z=4-x-y`. Now I want to plot the object in 3d.

My idea:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    grid,
    grid style={dashed,gray!30},
    smooth,
    xmin=-3, xmax=3,
    ymin=-2, ymax=4,
    %axis lines=middle,
    xlabel=$x$,
    xlabel style={below, anchor=north east,inner xsep=0pt},
    xtick={-2,...,2},
    ylabel=$y$,
    ylabel style={above,anchor=south,inner ysep=0pt},
    ytick={-2,...,3},
    zlabel=$z$,
    ztick={0,5,10},
]
\addplot3[name path=z,mesh,samples=20,domain=-4:4]{4-x-y};
\addlegendentry{$z=4-x-y$}

\addplot[red,name path=f1,mark=none,domain=-2:2,line legend] {3-x^2};
\addlegendentry{$f_{1}(x)$}

\addplot[blue,name path=f2,mark=none,domain=-1.25:1.25, line legend] {3*x^2-1};
\addlegendentry{$f_{2}(x)$}

\path[name path=lower,intersection segments={of=f1 and f2,sequence=B0 -- A1}];
\addplot[pattern=north west lines, pattern color=green]fill between[of=f2 and lower];
\addlegendentry{$\cal{A}$}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: 1]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: is it imposible to do? :/

Comment: At worst you can to assign the domains of every line by annoying `\ifnum`'s. So what possibility did you expect?

Comment: What kind of output do you expect?

Answer (score 2):

Basically, I draw the border of the region you are interested in by cuttinf it in two parts (y = 3-x^2 and y = 3x^2-1) and parametrizing it.

Finding the good colors so that everything is visible seems to be another problem.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    grid,
    grid style={dashed,gray!30},
    smooth,
    xmin=-3, xmax=3,
    ymin=-2, ymax=4,
    %axis lines=middle,
    xlabel=$x$,
    xlabel style={below, anchor=north east,inner xsep=0pt},
    xtick={-2,...,2},
    ylabel=$y$,
    ylabel style={above,anchor=south,inner ysep=0pt},
    ytick={-2,...,3},
    zlabel=$z$,
    ztick={0,5,10},
]


\addplot[red,name path=f1,mark=none,domain=-2:2,line legend] {3-x^2};
\addlegendentry{$f_{1}(x)$}

\addplot[blue,name path=f2,mark=none,domain=-1.25:1.25, line legend] {3*x^2-1};
\addlegendentry{$f_{2}(x)$}

\addplot3[surf,opacity=0.2,color=red,faceted color=red,domain=-1:1,y domain=0:1]({x},{3*x^2-1},{y*(5-x-3*x^2)});
\addplot3[surf,color=red,faceted color=red,opacity=0.2,domain=-1:1,y domain=0:1]({x},{3-x^2},{y*(x^2+1-x)});

\addplot3[surf,name path=z,faceted color=blue,color=blue,samples=20,domain=-3:3,opacity=0.1]{4-x-y};


\path[name path=lower,intersection segments={of=f1 and f2,sequence=B0 -- A1}];
\addplot[pattern=north west lines, pattern color=green]fill between[of=f2 and lower];


\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]